# How to Seed a table with Index Unique Data Annotation based on 2 columns with one nullable

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

I want to create a table where data uniqueness is based on multiple columns (2 or 3) but one of them can be null.
For example:

```
FRUIT   WEIGHT  UNIT
Apple
Apple   1       Kg
Apple   2       Kg
Orange
Orange  1       Kg
Orange  2       Kg
```

will all be considered as unique entries.
Can it be done with EF 6.1 Data Annotations?
I beleive I achieved that like this:

```
[Required]
[Index("UniqueIndx", 1)]
public string Name { get; set; }
[Index("UniqueIndx", 2)]
public float? Weight { get; set; }
[Index("UniqueIndx", 3, IsUnique = true)]
public FormulUnit? Unit { get; set; }
```

which produces:

```
public override void Up()
{
    AlterColumn("MyDb.Fruits", "Weight", c => c.Single());
    AlterColumn("MyDb.Fruits", "Unit", c => c.Int());
    CreateIndex("MyDb.Fruits", new[] { "Name", "Weight", "Unit" }, 
                 unique: true, name: "UniqueIndx");
}
```

From my understanding of Up method created by migration is that uniqueness is based on all 3 columns, not just last one I wrote that annotation to. This is ok for me, this is actually what I want.

I still have the problem of seeding that table. I'm getting errors on AddOrUpdate method like:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Nullable`1[System.Single]' and 'System.Single'.
```

for:

```
context.Fruits.AddOrUpdate(
    p => new {p.Name, p.Weight, p.Unit}, fr1, fr2, fr3
);
```

Am I missing something?
Thanks

Comment: what is `FormulUnit` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570634/equal-is-not-defined-between-type-nullableint32-and-int32 ?

Comment: FormulUnit is an enum.

Comment: What is the primary key of `Fruit` ?

Comment: Primary key for Fruit is in a base class that Fruit and other entities inherit from.

Answer (score 1):

I just debugged the [**`EF source code`**](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Migrations/DbSetMigrationsExtensions.cs), and the code that throws the error is inside [**`AddOrUpdate`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.idbsetextensions.addorupdate%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

Here is part of the code excerpt that causes error.

```
var matchExpression
    = identifyingProperties.Select(
        pi => Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Property(parameter, pi.Single()),
            Expression.Constant(pi.Last().GetValue(entity, null))))
```

Or you can replicate the error by doing this.

```
var fr1 = new Fruit { Weight = 1 };
var epe = Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(fr1), "Weight");
var ec = Expression.Constant(fr1.Weight);
var ee = Expression.Equal(epe, ec);
```

I'm not sure why `Float?` is not acceptable by [**`Expression.Equal`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352749%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), perhaps somebody else can explain.

But, if you can just use [**`Add`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.add%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) or manually checking whether to add or update, instead of `AddOrUpdate`, that will work.

Comment: I was thinking I was wrong trying AddOrUpdate, but I ran Into another problem later by not using AddOrUpdate. I'm very troubled now. I'll just cancel all Index annotations from my entity.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 2:**

Below is what I thought my mistake and gave a possible sollution. But then again I was wrong. Although below code adds new records to databse with index based on 3 criteria, because it creates new objects of anonymous type during process, you loose foreign key relations.
If you have a parent class, let's call it Grocery which holds many Fruits, seed method will not update those relations with given code below.

Back to work agin...

---

My logic is wrong.

If we have a unique index based on **multiple** criteria, how one can tell which record to update? A record with one different criteria out of 3 might be very well a new record, or maybe it's an old one to be updated but that is not something compiler can tell.

Each record need to be added manualy.

Thank you Yuliam.

**UPDATE:**
For those of you who fall into same dilema, here is how I solved this situation (with help of other Stackoverflow posts)

First, you must know that Fruit entity has a base entity with ID, so that's why you don't see it here.
Then to understand better here are steps needed to take:

1. Get your DbSet from context into an anonymous type list, stripped
   from properties that are not concern for comparison.
2. Put that anonymous type list into a strongly typed list (of your
   entity type, in this example: Fruit)
3. Make a new list where you only select from your seed objects that don't exist in database.
4. Add all of those new objects to context (and then context.save() )

   var SeedFruits = new List { fr1, fr2, fr3 };

   var result = from a in context.Fruits
                select new { a.Name, a.Weight, a.Unit };

   List DBFruitsList = result.AsEnumerable()
                 .Select(o => new Fruit
                 {
                     Name = o.Name,
                     Weight = o.Weight,
                     Unit = o.Unit
                 }).ToList();

   var UniqueFruitsList =
        from ai in SeedFruits
        where !DBFruitsList.Any(x => x.Name == ai.Name && x.Weight == ai.Weight && x.Unit == ai.Unit)
        select ai;

   foreach (Fruit fruittoupdate in UniqueFruitsList)
   {
       context.Fruits.Add(fruittoupdate);
   }